# Angular 6 style.property or ngStyle not updating when bound variable is being updated in component

Tags: javascript, angular, ng-style

I am trying to create a simple carousel and on click I am trying to update the style.transform on an element to update the translate3d so it will move. The variable that is bound in the component updates, but it does not update on the dom.

The slide function is what triggering the change in translate3d, and it is updating the variable inside the component. It is just not updating on the dom.

It works when I dynamically change the style.width.px.

Here is my component.

```
export class RecentNewsSliderComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {    

  @ViewChild('recentNewsSlider') recentNewsSlider;
  @Input() articles;

  newsContainerWidth: number;
  carousel: any = {};

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.setUpCarousel();
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    setTimeout(() => this.newsContainerWidth = this.getNewsContWidth(), 500);
  }

  setUpCarousel() {
    this.carousel.articlesLength = this.articles.length;
    this.carousel.controls = [];
    this.carousel.transform3d = 'translate3d(0, 0, 0)';
    let controlsNum = Math.ceil(this.articles.length / 3);

    for(let i = 0; i < controlsNum; i++) {
      this.carousel.controls.push({ i: i, active: i === 0 ? true : false });
    }
  }


  getNewsContWidth() {
    let totalWidth = 0;
    let children = Array.from(this.recentNewsSlider.nativeElement.children);    

    children.forEach((x: any) => {      
      totalWidth += x.offsetWidth;
    });

    this.carousel.containerWidth = totalWidth + (children.length * 20);

    return totalWidth + (children.length * 20);
  }

  slide(control) {
    let scrollTo = this.carousel.containerWidth /     this.carousel.controls.length;

    if(control.i === 0) {
      this.carousel.transform3d = 'translate3d(0, 0, 0)';
    } else {
      this.carousel.transform3d = `translate3d(${scrollTo}, 0, 0)`
    }    
  }

}
```

Here is my HTML.

```
<div class="news-wrapper container">
    <div #recentNewsSlider class="news-container" [style.width.px]="newsContainerWidth" [style.transform]="carousel.transform3d">
        <div *ngFor="let article of articles">
          <div class="news-article">
            <img src="{{ article.image }}">
            <div class="rollover">
              <h4>{{ article.title }}</h4>
              <button class="small">Read</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="news-control">
          <div class="dot" *ngFor="let control of carousel.controls" [ngClass]="{ 'active' : control.active }" (click)="slide(control)"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

I didn't include the px after the number.